# Why can't I sys_write from a pointer to stack memory, using int 0x80?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls

```
; NASM
push 30 ; '0'

mov rax, 4 ; write
mov rbx, 1 ; stdout
mov rcx, rsp ; ptr to character on stack
mov rdx, 1 ; length of string = 1
int 80h
```

The code above does not print anything to stdout. It works when i give it a ptr to a character in `section .data`. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Using x86-64 with int 80h smells so wrong in this day and age.

Comment: Have you checked the return value of `write`? Is it returning with `EFAULT`?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis yes it is returning -14. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`amd64` uses a different method for system calls than `int 0x80`, although that might still work with 32-bit libraries installed, etc. Whereas on `x86` one would do:

```
mov eax, SYSCALL_NUMBER
mov ebx, param1
mov ecx, param2
mov edx, param3
int 0x80
```

on `amd64` one would instead do this:

```
mov rax, SYSCALL_NUMBER_64 ; different from the x86 equivalent, usually
mov rdi, param1
mov rsi, param2
mov rdx, param3
syscall
```

For what you want to do, consider the following example:

```
        bits 64
        global _start

section .text

_start:
        push            0x0a424242
        mov             rdx, 04h
        lea             rsi, [rsp]
        call            write
        call            exit
exit:
        mov             rax, 60     ; exit()
        xor             rdi, rdi    ; errno
        syscall

write:
        mov             rax, 1      ; write()
        mov             rdi, 1      ; stdout
        syscall
        ret
```

Comment: I think the reason his code worked with an address in `.data` is that `.data` starts at an address that fits in 32b, so it isn't affected by passing it through the x86 `int 0x80` ABI.  The stack defaults to being mapped at a high address (where the high-bits are all 1s, rather than all 0s).

Answer (score 1):

30 decimal is the code of the ASCII "record separator". Whatever that is, it's probably not a printable character.

30 hexadecimal (30h or 0x30 in NASM parlance), on the other hand, is the code of the ASCII "0".

Also, you need to use the 64-bit ABI.

Comment: I did forget the h you are right, but after adding it its still not working. I even stepped through with gdb and rcx is being set to a ptr, when i query the value of that ptr it is 0x30 .... I have no idea what is wrong

Comment: In that case, I think you may be confusing the 32-bit ABI with the 64-bit ABI. See [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5022744/968261).

Comment: If that's too long to read, [here's a short example of using the write syscall in 64-bit mode](http://www.cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/linuxsyscalls/).