# Using sys_write from an x86_64 function that takes only a char* argument?

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64

I'm currently learning assembly and I would need some help with this simple program.

The say_something() function is created by x86_64 assembly (using NASM on 64-bit Linux) and is simply supposed to print out the phrase and the newline.

The main program is written in C and looks like this:

```
extern void say_something(char *);

int main(void) {
    say_something("First line.");
    say_something("Second sentence on another line.");

    return 0;
}
```

... and the content of the *.asm file is this:

```
section .text
    global say_something

say_something:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    mov rax, 4 ; syscall for write
    mov rbx, 1
    mov rcx, rdi
    int 0x80

    pop rbp
    ret
```

But apparently my ASM function is buggy, because when I compile the program and run it, the output is just some junk, whereas it's supposed to print this:

```
First line.
Second sentence on another line.
```

What changes should I do on my assembly part to make it work correctly?

Comment: Isn't `sys_write` 1 for x86_64? Also, you should set `rdx` to the number of bytes to write.

Comment: See http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/

Comment: amd64 system calls are done with syscall, not int $0x80 and have different numbers and a different calling convention. Who teaches beginners to do it wrongly like OP does?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why cant i sys\_write from a register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105871/why-cant-i-sys-write-from-a-register)

Comment: @Michael: This code is (unwisely) [using the 32-bit `int 0x80` ABI from 64-bit code, so the call numbers are from `unistd_32.h`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code).   The arg-passing registers are ebx,ecx,edx, etc. (*not* rdi,rsi,rdx, etc.), so you can only use 32-bit pointers and lengths.  But anyway, yes, you need `edx=strlen()`

Comment: @fuz: not really a duplicate.  The OP says it prints junk, rather than nothing, so it should work if they set `edx=strlen()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have one major problem here, and two other major problems that might not be visible with this particular caller:

- You forgot to set `edx` to the string length.  The system call you're using is
  `sys_write(int fd, const char *buf, size_t len);`, so the `len` you're passing is whatever garbage your caller left in `edx`.

If that doesn't make `sys_write` return `-EFAULT` without printing anything, then maybe you're printing a bunch of binary garbage before it detects a problem, if you ended up with a very large `len`?  Hmm, `write` probably checks the whole range before writing anything, so maybe you ended up with a medium-sized value in `edx` and just printed some binary garbage after your strings.  Your strings should be there at the start of your output, though.

Use `strace ./my_program` to find out, or GDB to look at `edx` before the call.  (`strace` won't actually work right for `int 0x80` from 64-bit code; it decodes as if you were using the native 64-bit `syscall` ABI).

- You clobber the caller's `rbx` without saving/restoring it, violating the calling convention (the x86-64 System V ABI) where `rbx` is a call-preserved register.  See http://agner.org/optimize/ for a nice doc about calling conventions.  This may have no effect; your `main` probably doesn't compile to code that uses `rbx` for anything, so the `rbx` you're destroying is "owned" by the CRT start function that calls `main`.

  Strangely, you save/restore `rbp` even though you don't use it at all.

**Most importantly, you're [using the 32-bit `int 0x80` ABI from 64-bit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code)**!!  This is why I've been saying that `write` takes its `length` are in `edx`, not `rdx`, because the 32-bit `int 0x80` ABI is exactly the same ABI that 32-bit user-space can use, where it only looks at the low 32 bits of registers.

Your code will break with pointers outside the low 32 bits of virtual address space.  e.g. if you compiled with `gcc -fPIE -pie`, even those string literals in the `.rodata` section will be outside the low 32 bits, and `sys_write` will probably return `-EFAULT` without doing anything.

[`-pie` is the default for gcc on many modern Linux distros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code), so you're "lucky"(?) that your program printed anything at all instead of just having `write` fail with `-EFAULT`.  You aren't checking error return values, and it *doesn't* segfault your program the way it would if you tried to read/write from a bad point in user-space, so it fails silently.

As @fuz points out, [Why cant i sys_write from a register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105871/why-cant-i-sys-write-from-a-register) shows some example code for using the 64-bit `syscall` for `sys_write`, but it hard-codes a length.  You're going to need to `strlen` your string, either with the libc function or with a loop.  (Or a slow but compact `repe scasb`).