# Print characters from the stack after pushing them?

Tags: linux, assembly, stack, x86-64, nasm

my name is Nick and I am student. I was given homework to do in NASM assembly in 64-bit compiler. This is totally new to me and I have been struggling with this task for last two days. I got to the point where my code works, but it does not print anything at all. I don't know what to do/what to change so it can print the output of this program. I was given number 629 as input, my program should do the following: It has to split the 629 in 6 2 9 and each of this numbers to push on stack, once that loop is done, it should take those numbers from stack then switch them to string and print them on screen one by one. I would much appreciate if anyone could confirm that this code is going to do the task and how I could fix code so it could print the output.
(for those who are wondering what certain words in code mean novi_red=new_line, stampaj=print, petlja=loop)

```
section .data
    novi_red db ' ', 10    
    number dd 629
section .text
    global _start
    stampaj:
        push rax
        push rbx
        mov eax, 4         
        mov ebx, 1         
        int 0x80           
        pop rbx
        pop rax
        ret
_start:
    mov eax, [number]
    mov ecx, 3  
petlja:
    mov ebx, 10  
    xor edx, edx  
    div ebx  
    add dl, '0'  
    push rdx  
    dec ecx  
    cmp ecx, 0  
    jne petlja  
    pop rax
    mov ebx, 1
    mov rcx, rax
    mov edx, 1
    call stampaj
    mov edx, 2
    mov ecx, novi_red
    call stampaj
    pop rax
    mov rcx, rax
    call stampaj
    mov edx, 2
    mov ecx, novi_red
    call stampaj
    pop rax
    mov rcx, rax
    call stampaj   
    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80
```

This code works in compiler, but for some reason it doesn't print the output (or I don't know how to do that).

Comment: If you are writing 64bit code, I believe you're supposed to use [syscall](https://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/) instead of int 0x80.  Note that syscall uses different parameters than int 0x80, so you can't just change the one line.

Comment: This looks like the same attempt as [How to push number on stack and print in assembly NASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77767647) .  As I commented there, you need to pass a *pointer* to the character, not the value itself.  And since characters are on the stack, the address isn't 32-bit so you can't use the 32-bit `int 0x80` ABI.  [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730) / [Writing a putchar in Assembly for x86\_64 with 64 bit Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50681077) .

Comment: You should be doing something like `mov rsi, rsp` / `mov edi, 1` / `mov edx, 1` / `mov eax, 1` / `syscall`  (`write(1, stack_pointer, 1)`, where `__NR_write` = 1 for x86-64 Linux.)  Then `add rsp, 8` or `pop rcx` to discard the character.

Comment: [Why can't I sys\_write from a pointer to stack memory, using int 0x80?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10105871)

Comment: Hi Peter, as you mentioned above it is actually same attempt. But the only difference are our input numbers. She has input 625, while I got 629. My code runs without errors in https://rextester.com/l/nasm_online_compiler this compiler, but it does not print the output. While I appreciate all the tips that David and you wrote to me, I personally dont understand none of that. We have had only 2 hours of lecture about assembly, which is absurd in my opinion, where we did 3 pretty easy tasks in compare to this. All the task we did in class were with int 0x80, we didnt use syscall at all.

Comment: I get the idea of using pointer (I kinda understand it from knowing basics in c++) that could be the fix, but I dont know how to implement it.

Comment: You mean [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894/2189500)?  Peter has already linked to this answer for you.  In the section on `If you just need the string without printing it` it shows how to write an integer to a buffer.

Comment: @rtsirobija: Didn't see your reply since you didn't @ notify me.  (You get notified of all comments under your own question, but I don't.)  Building without errors tells you very little about the correctness of a program in asm, just that each instruction is valid on its own.  The fact that it doesn't segfault tells you it reaches the `exit` system call, but nothing else. All of the other `int 0x80` system calls *do* return errors, you just didn't check for them with code or by single-stepping it in a debugger.  Like I said, you need to pass valid pointers; I linked multiple examples.

Comment: Run your program under `strace` to have it show you what system calls your program actually made..  (IDK if there's an online IDE that can do that.)  Without a debugger or `strace`, doing anything in asm will be **much** harder.  As you can see, you get zero symptoms so you don't know which part of your program didn't work the way you expected.  Install a light-weight Linux distro in a VM or emulator (doesn't even need a GUI, you can SSH in or use the text console.)

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate because I think the code would work if you fixed the two thing you're doing wrong: passing values instead of pointers to `write` system calls (so it returns `-EFAULT`), and using `int 0x80` in 64-bit code: with data on the stack, you *need* the 64-bit `syscall` interface.  It would be better to use a loop instead of unrolling a certain number of digits, like in Ira's answer on [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13166064)